# cap deploy throws "Ruby version is 2.2.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.3", except my Ruby version is 2.5.3

Tags: ruby, capistrano

Out of absolutely nowhere (not an exaggeration: I deployed two hours before this exception started happening), `cap production deploy` stopped working and is throwing this error:

```
Your Ruby version is 2.2.5, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.3
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

Except I'm using 2.5.3, as specified in both `gemfile` and in `.ruby-version`.

This is what's in my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.5.3'
```

I'm using rvm. `ruby -v` returns `ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin18]`, and ruby is set to global. I've tried running `gem update bundler`, `gem install bundler` followed by `bundle install`, `bundle`, and deleted `gemfile.lock`.

```
$ bundle env
Bundler           1.17.1
Platforms         ruby, x86_64-darwin-18
Ruby              2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin18]
Full Path         /Users/mirai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby
Config Dir        /Users/mirai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/etc
RubyGems          2.7.8
Gem Home          /Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@greentea-b2b
Gem Path          /Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@greentea- 
b2b:/Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global
User Path         /Users/mirai/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
Bin Dir           /Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@greentea-b2b/bin

$ which -a bundle
/Users/mirai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
```

Edit: Output of `$ gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.8
- RUBY VERSION: 2.5.3 (2018-10-18 patchlevel 105) [x86_64-darwin18]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@mirai-b2b
- USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/mirai/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/mirai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@greentea-b2b/bin
- SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/mirai/.gem/specs
- SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/mirai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/etc
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
- ruby
- x86_64-darwin-18
- GEM PATHS:
 - /Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@greentea-b2b
 - /Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org/"]
 - "update" => "--env-shebang"
 - "benchmark" => false
 - "install" => "--env-shebang"
 - "gem" => "-n/usr/local/bin"
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
- SHELL PATH:
 - /Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@greentea-b2b/bin
 - /Users/mirai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/bin
 - /Users/mirai/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin
 - /Users/mirai/.rvm/bin
 - /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin
 - /usr/local/bin
 - /usr/bin
 - /bin
 - /usr/sbin
 - /sbin
 - /opt/local/bin
 - /opt/local/sbin
 - /usr/local/MacGPG2/bin
 - /opt/X11/bin
```

I'm using AWS. `bundle exec cap production deploy` throws the same error.

Comment: It would be beneficial if you provide information about the cloud provider, that you use for the deployment?

Comment: Can you add to your post the output of `gem env` and perhaps anything relevant in Capfile

Comment: Try `bundle exec cap production deploy` this will execute in the context of bundler

Comment: @lacostenycoder added to the post. There's nothing relevant in capfile except `require "capistrano/rvm"`.

Comment: @engineersmnky Should've added it to the post, but `bundle exec cap production deploy` throws the same error.

Comment: Reading the docs, `config/deploy/production.rb` is the configuration file that is run when you invoke your command. What does that file look like?